# UnAuthorizedAccessException serial port while opening the port from the dll

Tags: c#, dll, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm using the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class in C#. UnAuthorizedAccessException is thrown while opening the serial port from my helper class which resides in a different dll. while opening the port is successful if the port get opened from the win form itself!

```
_portNames = new List<string>(); 
_portNames.AddRange(SerialPort.GetPortNames()); 
_serialPort = new SerialPort(); 
_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived); 
_serialPort.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_ErrorReceived);

var index = 0; 
while (!_serialPort.IsOpen && index < _portNames.Count)
{ 
    try
    { 
        _serialPort.PortName = _portNames[index++]; 
        _serialPort.Open(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ee) 
    { 
    _logger.Log(ee.Message, EventLogEntryType.Warning); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that a downloaded dll?

Comment: no, i've written the dll. here it is

Comment: _portNames = new List<string>();
_portNames.AddRange(SerialPort.GetPortNames());
_serialPort = serialPort ?? new SerialPort();
_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);
 _serialPort.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_ErrorReceived);

Comment: var index = 0;
while (!_serialPort.IsOpen && index < _portNames.Count){
try{
_serialPort.PortName = _portNames[index++];
_serialPort.Open();
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
_logger.Log(ee.Message, EventLogEntryType.Warning);
}
}

Comment: I've edited your code into your question from your comments - perhaps you can check if ok and click the *edit* link underneath your question to make any more changes.

Comment: You get that exception when the port is already in use.  That could be another process that opened the port before you did.  The most common mistake is that it is in fact *your* program that already has it opened.  Do not attempt to open it in your "form" and also in your DLL.  You must instead pass a reference to the SerialPort you created in your form to the code in the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

already an opened port on COM1

thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should always check that the serial port isn't already open when you open the port. There may be another application that has opened the COM port.

Try this code just above your `_serialPort.Open()` statement:

```
try
{ 
    _serialPort.PortName = _portNames[index++];

    if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Concat(_serialPort.PortName, " is already opened by another application!"));
    }
    else
    {
        _serialPort.Open();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution will not work. The `IsOpen` property is only used to track if the instance already called `Open`. It does not check if any other application has the port opened. [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.isopen(v=vs.110).aspx) `The IsOpen property tracks whether the port is open for use by the caller, not whether the port is open by any application on the machine.`